# Reveal text within transparent overlay

Tags: javascript

I've an image, and I'm making it transparent on click, so it reveals the background, Making the illusion of an overlay.

I'd like to also show some text in the center of the background, so it appears when the background reveals, how to do it?

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/yLJGzYr

Code:

```
$('.tricky').click(function(){
    $('img').addClass("tricky_image");
});
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Codepen multiple images in grid

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/qBNLLoW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. If you have any questions, please let me know. You can also add a border if you want to match the reference image better.

```js
  $('.imageDiv').click(function(){
    $('img').addClass("tricky_image");
    $(".text").css("display", "inline");
});
```

```css
.imageContainer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.tricky_image {
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}

.text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageContainer">
  
  <div class='imageDiv' id = 'test'>
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/08_Dota_2_140x175.jpg" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="text">text here</div>
</div>
```

Updated answer:

The key thing here is remembering how the DOM works.
you had `$('.imageDiv').click(function() {...` which will only allow you to find the children of the image div, which the `text` class is not part of. I switched it to `('.imageContainer')` which can traverse the DOM properly to find `text` as it is a child of `imageContainer`.  Also `$(this).find(".text").toggleClass("display-inline");` does not work because `display-inline` is not a class. I created a new class called `addText` which now hold the properties `text` had before where `text` now serves to hide the text until needed. Let me know in the comments if this works for you.

```js
$('.imageContainer').click(function() {
  $(this).find('img').toggleClass("tricky_image");
  $(this).find('.text').toggleClass("addText");
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.flip-card {
  border-style: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #222e36ef;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* background overlay - text */

.imageContainer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.tricky_image {
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}

.text {
 display: none;
}
.addText{
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8">

  <section id="team">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="grid">

        <div class="imageContainer">

          <div class='imageDiv' id='test'>
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/06_Counter_Strike_GO_140x175.jpg" />
          </div>

          <div class="text">text here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="imageContainer">

          <div class='imageDiv' id='test'>
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/06_Counter_Strike_GO_140x175.jpg" />
          </div>

          <div class="text">text here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="imageContainer">

          <div class='imageDiv' id='test'>
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/06_Counter_Strike_GO_140x175.jpg" />
          </div>

          <div class="text">text here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="imageContainer">

          <div class='imageDiv' id='test'>
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/06_Counter_Strike_GO_140x175.jpg" />
          </div>

          <div class="text">text here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="imageContainer">

          <div class='imageDiv' id='test'>
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/06_Counter_Strike_GO_140x175.jpg" />
          </div>

          <div class="text">text here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="imageContainer">

          <div class='imageDiv' id='test'>
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/06_Counter_Strike_GO_140x175.jpg" />
          </div>

          <div class="text">text here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="imageContainer">

          <div class='imageDiv' id='test'>
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/06_Counter_Strike_GO_140x175.jpg" />
          </div>

          <div class="text">text here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="imageContainer">

          <div class='imageDiv' id='test'>
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/06_Counter_Strike_GO_140x175.jpg" />
          </div>

          <div class="text">text here</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: hi, sample, I've added your code and made some modifications (codepen in original question **update 1**), but text is not showing. May you look into it? ty.

Comment: I will look at it when I have time in about 40 minutes. However, as I am trying to build reputation (I am new) I would ask that since I answered the original question it should be marked correct. Thanks

Comment: Hi sample, may you take a look into it today?

Comment: I already updated it 15 hours ago... do you not see the new part?

Comment: If you don't see the updated answer let me know and I will figure out some other way to send it to you (eg. stackoverflow chat). I left the original answer up along with the updated one because it is more simple and will have a better chance of helping others if they end up reading the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I see it now, thank you, I'll test it in the next hours. Sample!. Could you upvote my question, pls?

Comment: hmmm, I'm not the one that downvoted it but I can upvote your question if you want. I think the reason they downvoted it was because you used an external sandbox for your code (instead of a code snippet). Also you should show the research you did before asking the question so that people don't think you are making them do work for you. That said, if you had asked the question properly, I probably wouldn't be the  only one to answer it and hence would not necessarily have been marked correct, so i'll upvote it. Just write a better question next time, more people will answer it.